# Need help calculating prices in dropdown and checkboxes together

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to calculate the correct price. It works great until I change the dropdown quantity if the checkbox is already checked.

Below is my html code, it's two check boxes a label(span) which contains the price and a dropdown menu that contains the quantity.

Keep in mind though, there are over 30 rows of items, I just included 2 in the JFiddle.

Here is the code:

**http://jsfiddle.net/M9uZ2/**

**please see the JFIDDLE Link above for the rest of it**

For the dropdown list above, I thought of something like this, but it's not working and probably a bad way to do it.

```
$("#MainContent_ddlLipoB12").bind('change', function () {

                if ($('#MainContent_cbLipoB12').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#MainContent_cbLipoB12').prop('checked', false);
                    $("#MainContent_cbLipoB12").click();
                }
            });
```

Any ideas would be appreciated! I tried several different methods and the price would never calculate correctly.

Comment: is my solution useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are having multiple checkboxes and drop downs, it is difficult to have unique ids as the code is needed to replicated many times.
Better you can have a class for checkboxes and dropdowns and trigger the function that updates the total charge on changing quantity. I have added a class for the drop downs and called a function to update the total. Here is the function body which will work for the entire table,

```
function calculateTotal() {
  var chargetotal = 0;
  $('#tab > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    if ($('td:nth-child(1) > span >input', this).is(':checked')) {
    var price = parseFloat($('td:nth-child(3)', this).text().replace('$', ''));
    var quantity = $('td:nth-child(4) option:selected', this).val();
    chargetotal = chargetotal + price*quantity;
  }
  $('#MainContent_txtTotal').val(chargetotal);
  });
}
```

call this function on change event of checkboxes and dropdowns. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M9uZ2/2/)